# JWT Guard returning "Converting circular structure to JSON"

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs

i have this nest code to verify the bearer token of a user after they login in but it gives me the error:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
|     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
--- property 'socket' closes the circle
```

this is my login code and my attempt to authorize the user:
user.module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Level]),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'abc123',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60d' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, JwtStrategy],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

user.controller:

```
import { jwtAuthGuard } from 'src/guards/jwt.guard';
 @Get("")
    @UseGuards(jwtAuthGuard)
    getUser(@Req() req: Request) {
        return this.UserService.getUser(req)
    }
```

jwt.guard:

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class jwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt'){
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {        
        return super.canActivate(context)
    }

}
```

jwt.strategy:

```
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'abc123', // Access the environment variable
    });
  }

  validate(payload: any) {
    return payload;
  }
}
```

this is my entire code i omitted some of the imports and some code in the controller and module in other not to make this post too long

Comment: What does `this.UserService.getUser(req)` return?

Comment: just approximaelty 3 mins ago, i found out the problem is from there, i'll post the solution soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is in the user.conroller, i was passing the entire `req` inside the `getUser(req)` method, this is how the code should have been written:

```
 @Get("")
    @UseGuards(jwtAuthGuard)
    getUser(@Req() req: Request) {
        return this.UserService.getUser(req.body)
    }
```

so from this:`getUser(req)` to `getUser(req.body)`